# Horizontally align multi-line cell in table

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment

I want to horizontally align two cells with two lines in a table environment, something like this:

```
-------------------
| A long    | foo |
|           | ----|
| multiline | bar |
-------------------
```

What I'm getting is a blank line under `foo` as the long multi-line takes up more vertical space, and `bar` is pushed down. In this image, I don't want the blank space between 'First text' and 'Second text', or 'Second text' and 'Third text'.

[image: Lines not correct]

I thought putting the top left cell into a `minipage` would make it flow into the blank space I provided in the second row, but that didn't work. My MWE is below.

#### How can I align my cells correctly?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tb]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.6\textwidth}}
        \hline
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth} A long\\line\end{minipage} & First text\\
                                                                      & Second Text\\
        A second\\Line & Third Text\\
                       & Fourth Text\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\textwidth}p{0.6\textwidth}}
\hline
A long & First text\\
line & Second Text\\
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{A second\\ Line}} & Third Text\\
 & Fourth Text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the first example, is there any difference in spacing between the lines if I spread them over two cells? I can't see one, but I wouldn't expect it to be big if it existed.

Comment: @simont Sirry, but I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Which lines would be spread over which cells?